# Cannot get wifi to work or even show up at all in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

After setting up the wifi network profile in `/etc/netctl/` and run `netctl start [my_network_profile]` I get this message:

```
Job for netctl@wlp2s0\x2d[my_network].service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

Also I have gnome desktop environment installed and wifi does not show up in settings or the system tray, like it doesn't even exist.

The output for `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]
```

and here's the output for `dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    3.316448] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.316486] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    3.609531] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
[    3.627583] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: fc:f8:ae:3e:9a:f4
[    3.853230] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.855957] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

..and here's the output for `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi not found in directory /lib/modules/5.7.6-arch1-1
```

Also, when I use `wifi-menu` (which in my understanding uses netctl), it does run and discovers the wifi networks but it never connects.

Comment: 1) Identify your Wifi hardware (USB? PCI?) Edit your question with the information (`lsusb`, `lspci` for vendor id). 2) Look at `dmesg` after boot for suspicious errors. 3) Most common problem: You have hardware which needs a special driver or firmware, possibly from a recent kernel, possibly by additionally installing it.

Comment: I edited my question providing more info.

Comment: Googling for "intel wireless n 7260 driver linux arch" lead to [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1502967#p1502967), so it looks like you need a current kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to connect by following the [Network configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Network_configuration) hyperlink in the arch wiki install guide (that I have skipped during installation) which finally led me to this link https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi where I could download the iwlwifi firmware for my Intel Wireless 7260 and then installed it simply by copying `iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode` file into the directory `/lib/firmware/` as instructed in the README file.

Now it works fine and it also connects automatically on reboot.